# MQTT reconnects indefinitely despite it manages to connect

Tags: java, android, mqtt

I'm using this library:

https://github.com/fusesource/mqtt-client

With this options:

```
 MQTT mqtt = new MQTT();
 mqtt.setClientId(deviceId() + "-device");
 mqtt.setHost(getResources().getString(R.string.jms_uri));
 mqtt.setUserName(getResources().getString(R.string.jms_user));
 mqtt.setPassword(getResources().getString(R.string.jms_password));
 mqtt.setReconnectDelay(10000);
 mqtt.setReconnectDelayMax(60000);
 connection = mqtt.futureConnection();
 connection.connect().await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And sometimes (I cannot reproduce it) it seems to loose the connection and starts to reconnect "crazily". According to the JMS, it is managing to connect every time but, I don't know why, it keeps reconnecting (closing and starting a connection). The only thing I can do when this happens is to stop the app. In the meantime, the re-connection to the JMS is not fruitful as it is not able to receive any message.

It starts to reconnect all the time without waiting the ms I have set for the reconnection delay.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you have 2 client trying to connect with the same client id. Client id's must be unique, when a second client connects with the same id the broker will disconnect the first, which will immediately try and reconnect which kicks off the second client and this then carries on in a loop.

If you look at the broker logs it should be really easy to spot this is the case.

Comment: I will check it out. I was thinking that the reason you say is the most logical one. However, I thought that the mqtt reconnection was going to work well despite you have set a client-id... Thanks